# hive UDF - convert StringObjectInspector to String

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, user-defined-functions, hadoop2

I am writing generic UDF. If I use UDF directly it works, however if I use UDF with other function (distinct, max, min) it's not even calling `evaluate` function.

I want to see what's happening and so trying to log the values. However need to understand how to convert `StringObjectInspector` to `String`.

**Code**

```java
@Description(name = "Decrypt", value = "Decrypt the Given Column", extended = "SELECT Decrypt('Hello World!');")
public class Decrypt extends GenericUDF {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    PrimitiveObjectInspector col;
    StringObjectInspector databaseName;
    StringObjectInspector schemaName;
    StringObjectInspector tableName;
    StringObjectInspector colName;

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments) throws UDFArgumentException {
        System.out.println("******************************      initialize called    ******************************");
        logger.info("******************************      initialize called    ******************************");
        if (arguments.length != 5) {
            throw new UDFArgumentLengthException("Decrypt only takes 4 arguments: T, String, String, String");
        }

        ObjectInspector colObject = arguments[0];
        ObjectInspector databaseNameObject = arguments[1];
        ObjectInspector schemaNameObject = arguments[2];
        ObjectInspector tableNameObject = arguments[3];
        ObjectInspector colNameNameObject = arguments[4];


        if (    !(databaseNameObject instanceof StringObjectInspector) ||
                !(schemaNameObject instanceof StringObjectInspector) ||
                !(tableNameObject instanceof StringObjectInspector) ||
                !(colNameNameObject instanceof StringObjectInspector)
        ) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("Error: databaseName, schemeName, tableName and ColName should be String");
        }

        this.col = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) colObject;
        this.databaseName = (StringObjectInspector) databaseNameObject;
        this.tableName = (StringObjectInspector) tableNameObject;
        this.schemaName = (StringObjectInspector) schemaNameObject;
        this.colName = (StringObjectInspector) colNameNameObject;

        logger.info("******************************      initialize end    ******************************");
        logger.info(col.toString());
        logger.info(col);
        logger.info(databaseNameObject.toString());
        logger.info(databaseNameObject);
        logger.info(colName.toString());
        logger.info(colName);
        logger.info(colNameNameObject);
        logger.info(colNameNameObject.toString());
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] deferredObjects) throws HiveException {
        System.out.println("******************** Decrypt ********************");
        logger.info("******************** Decrypt ******************** ");
        if(col.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[0].get()) == null){
            return null;
        }
        String stringToDecrypt = col.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[0].get()).toString();
        String database = databaseName.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[1].get());
        String schema = schemaName.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[2].get());
        String table = tableName.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[3].get());
        String col = colName.getPrimitiveJavaObject(deferredObjects[4].get());

        return new Text(AES.decrypt(stringToDecrypt, database, schema, table, col));
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] strings) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to call your UDF in sub-query and then call max/min on the resulting column?

Answer (score 0):

Try `getPrimitiveJavaObject` method instead of `toString`, [more details](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/StringObjectInspector.html#getPrimitiveJavaObject(java.lang.Object)).

Another thought on your problem, check out optimization flags:

- vectorization: `hive.vectorized.execution`, `hive.vectorized.execution.enabled`, `hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.groupby.enabled`
- Cost-Based Optimization: `hive.cbo.enable`
- predicate push down: `hive.optimize.ppd`

Check if those flags are enabled/disabled by typing `set <option>`, e.g., `set hive.optimize.ppd;`, in hive shell, and try to switch the value.